# Как найти схожее значения в DOM элементах?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу добавить активный класс в список с городами, как это сделать, ниже приведен мой код:

```js
var cityChose = $('.region-show').text();

var geolocationCity = $('.geolocation__list li a').attr('data-city');

alert(cityChose);
alert(geolocationCity);

if (cityChose === geolocationCity) {
  $('.geolocation__list a').addClass('active');
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="region-show">Владивосток</div>

<br><hr><br>

<ul class="geolocation__list">
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Москва">Москва</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Санкт-Петербург">Санкт-Петербург</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Алматы">Алматы</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Барнаул">Барнаул</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Владивосток">Владивосток</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Владимир">Владимир</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Воронеж">Воронеж</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Екатеринбург">Екатеринбург</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Казань">Казань</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Калининград">Калининград</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Кемерово">Кемерово</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Новосибирск">Новосибирск</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Омск">Омск</a></li>
</ul>
```

Получается лишь получить у DIV значение, а вот значение по всему списку получить не могу, получаю только первый результат, что бы сравнить если значения одинаковы, то добавляем класс к пункту в списке.

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "схожие значения"?

Comment: Получается лишь получить у DIV значение (Владивосток), а вот значение по всему списку UL получить не могу, получаю только первый результат, что бы сравнить если значения одинаковы, то добавляем класс к пункту в списке.

Как пройтись по всему списку UL найти один и тот же город и присвоить класс пункту, где он был найден?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно воспользоваться любым циклом, например `.each`:

```js
var cityChose = $('.region-show').text();

var geolocationCities = $('.geolocation__list li a');

geolocationCities.each(function(i, el){
  if (cityChose === $(el).attr('data-city')) {
    $(el).addClass('active');
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="region-show">Владивосток</div>

<br><hr><br>

<ul class="geolocation__list">
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Москва">Москва</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Санкт-Петербург">Санкт-Петербург</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Алматы">Алматы</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Барнаул">Барнаул</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Владивосток">Владивосток</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Владимир">Владимир</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Воронеж">Воронеж</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Екатеринбург">Екатеринбург</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Казань">Казань</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Калининград">Калининград</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Кемерово">Кемерово</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Новосибирск">Новосибирск</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Омск">Омск</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает. С циклами у меня проблема, буду изучать их усиленно!

Answer (score 2):

При получении значения методом [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) получается только значение **первого** элемента в коллекции, об этом написано в описании метода:

> Get the value of an attribute for the **first element** in the set of matched elements

---

Вместо этого нужно пробежаться по элементам коллекции и добавить класс тем, чей атрибут совпадает с нужным значением, для этого можно воспользоваться методом [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

```js
var cityChose = $('.region-show').text();

var geolocationCity = $('.geolocation__list li a');
geolocationCity.each((i, v) => {
  if ($(v).attr('data-city') == cityChose) {
    $(v).addClass('active');
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="region-show">Владивосток</div>

<br>
<hr><br>

<ul class="geolocation__list">
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Москва">Москва</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Санкт-Петербург">Санкт-Петербург</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Алматы">Алматы</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Барнаул">Барнаул</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Владивосток">Владивосток</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Владимир">Владимир</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Воронеж">Воронеж</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Екатеринбург">Екатеринбург</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Казань">Казань</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Калининград">Калининград</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Кемерово">Кемерово</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Новосибирск">Новосибирск</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Омск">Омск</a></li>
</ul>
```

Также можно воспользоваться методом `addClass`, который может принимать функцию в качестве параметра:

```js
var cityChose = $('.region-show').text();

var geolocationCity = $('.geolocation__list li a');

geolocationCity.addClass(function(i, className) {
  if ($(this).attr('data-city') == cityChose) {
    return className + ' ' + 'active';
  }
  return className;
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="region-show">Владивосток</div>

<br>
<hr><br>

<ul class="geolocation__list">
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Москва">Москва</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Санкт-Петербург">Санкт-Петербург</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Алматы">Алматы</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Барнаул">Барнаул</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Владивосток">Владивосток</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Владимир">Владимир</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Воронеж">Воронеж</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Екатеринбург">Екатеринбург</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Казань">Казань</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Калининград">Калининград</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Кемерово">Кемерово</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Новосибирск">Новосибирск</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Омск">Омск</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

Ну и всегда можно сразу выбрать нужные элементы, к которым уже будет применяться `addClass`:

```js
var cityChose = $('.region-show').text();

$(`.geolocation__list li a[data-city=${cityChose}]`).addClass('active');
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="region-show">Владивосток</div>

<br>
<hr><br>

<ul class="geolocation__list">
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Москва">Москва</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Санкт-Петербург">Санкт-Петербург</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Алматы">Алматы</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Барнаул">Барнаул</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Владивосток">Владивосток</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Владимир">Владимир</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Воронеж">Воронеж</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Екатеринбург">Екатеринбург</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Казань">Казань</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Калининград">Калининград</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Кемерово">Кемерово</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Новосибирск">Новосибирск</a></li>
  <li><a class="city" data-city="Омск">Омск</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Опередили:)
Вот работающий код:
Обратите внимание что element - это не объект jquery, а объект DOM

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

            var cityChose = $('.region-show').text();

            var geolocationCitys = $('.geolocation__list li a');
            for (let i=0;i<geolocationCitys.length;i++) {
                let element=geolocationCitys[i];
                let tgt=element.getAttribute('data-city');
                if (tgt == cityChose) {

                    element.classList.add('active');
                    break;
                }
            }

        });
```